# How to complete data migration without "invalid method name" error from Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.2 to Version 1.0.0?

Tags: migration, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to migrate data from Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.2 to Version 1.0.0. I checked the official user guide and use the DataMigrationExample to implement data replication, but the execution fails. The error reported "Invalid method name: executeQueryStatementV2". I also checked the "load tsfile" method to do data migration, but because there is a special character "-" in the path name of my time series, I also fail to use "load tsfile". Can anyone suggest how can I successfully complete my data migration process?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o17DJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Apache IoTDB cannot use the session of Version 1.0 to connect to Version 0.13 to migrate data, however session of Version 0.13 can be used to connect to version 1.0. You can try to use the DataMigrationExample of Version 0.13 in user guide to try again.

Comment: Could you provide a link to this example?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).